# How does one arrive at the two qubit matrix that represents a gate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

The two qubit CNOT gate is represented by a [2x2 matrix](https://quantiki.org/wiki/cnot). However, it is also represented [pictorally](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/CNOT_gate.svg).

How does one arrive at that matrix representation? I am not looking for "take a diagonal matrix and place the X matrix in the lower corner."

I know each line represents a qubit, and time travels left to right. What is the relation between the top and bottom line, the significance of the black dot (see link below since I cannot post more than 2 links). I know it denotes a controlled operation, I want to know what happens to that qubit after it encounters the black dot).

I have read up on wiki, but an still a bit confused. Please don't answer "in PhD terminology."

For example, could you please walk me through what is happening to each qubit in example 4.18 (see link below since I cannot post more than 2 links)?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199683/ http://people.math.gatech.edu/~jeanbel/4782/Year09/problem207.pdf

Comment: The top line in the pictorial representation is the "control qubit", the bottom one is the "target qubit". Black dot means "gate acts if this qubit (control qubit) is in state $|1\rangle$". The crossed circle means "when gate acts (control qubit is $|1\rangle$) this qubit (target qubit) gets flipped or 'added modulo 2 with the control qubit'". That is, if target qubit is initially $|0\rangle$, then after the CNOT it is $|(0+1)\;\text{mod}\;2\rangle = |1\rangle$. If initially it is $|1\rangle$, then after it is $|(1+1)\;\text{mod}\; 2\rangle = |0\rangle$.

Comment: Since you like Quantiki, read here: https://quantiki.org/wiki/basic-concepts-quantum-computation. Scroll down until first grey figure. It has what you are looking for.

Comment: @udrv If I gave you the Z gate, or Hadamard, and asked for the 4x4 matrix, I cannot doa modulo 2 which is the case for CNOT. Then, how do I proceed?

Comment: Write the action of the gate on each of the basis states. For example, the Z gate acts on a single qubit /w basis states |0> and |1>. Leaves |0> unchanged, takes |1> to -|1>. So  Z|0> = 1|0> + 0 |1>, Z|1> = 0|0> - 1|1>, matrix is ( 1  0; 0 -1). CNOT acts on 2 quits, /w basis states |00>, |01>, |10>, |11>. Leaves input unchanged if 1st qubit is |0>, flips 2nd qubit if 1st qubit is |1>: CNOT|00>= 1 |00>+ 0|01>+ 0|10>+ 0|11>, CNOT|01>= 0 |00>+ 1|01>+ 0|10>+ 0|11>, CNOT|10>= 0 |00>+ 0|01>+ 0|10>+ 1|11>, CNOT|11>= 0 |00>+ 0|01>+ 1|10>+ 0|11>, matrix is (1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 0 1; 0 0 1 0).